# Omniauth-slack scope error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, slack-api, slack

I would like to receive both a webhook url and the list of channels but have been unable to with the following [scopes](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-scopes#scopes/):

- 'channels:read,incoming-webhook' (This only has the single channel that was selected)
- 'channels:list,incoming-webhook' (This says: OAuth Error: invalid_scope: Invalid scope channels:list)

How can I get this information in one `oauth`?

[Here](https://github.com/kmrshntr/omniauth-slack/issues/22/) is another site I used to try to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Now I understand that what I was trying to do is no possible. channels:list is a method and so you you have to make another 'get' to get this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`channels.list` is a method and so you you have to make another 'get' to get this data. Here is an example: https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list/test

Comment: Yup, the `channels:read` scope gives you access to two methods: `channels.list`, and `channels.info`. As explained here: https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-scopes